# Docker keeps pushing same hashes

Tags: docker

I'm not sure if I'm using docker wrong but I have a base image called `repo/base` and it looks like

```
# Pull base image.
FROM centos:centos7

# add yum repos

ADD yum-repos/* /etc/yum.repos.d/
ADD certs/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7 /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

# Upgrading system
RUN rpm --import http://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch && \
    yum -y install  epel-release \
                    wget \
                    git \
                    tar \
                    nodejs \
                    npm \
                    libicu-devel \
                    logstash-forwarder \
                    rhnpush \
                    monit \
                    java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel


ADD runner/* /
RUN chmod +x /runner.sh && chmod +x /service-wrapper.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/runner.sh"]
```

Really not that big of a deal. I push this to an artifactory. Then I create a test image from it

```
FROM repo/base

RUN echo "foo"
```

Build it and push it to the repo.  Here it looks like the same hashes are being pushed out AGAIN, so its as if docker isn't registering that the images already exist remote.

Is this normal or is it somehow related to my remote artifactory?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually pushing?  Never used Artifactory as Docker repo,  but with DockerHub it always attempts to push every layer,  but once it finds out that it the image with the hash already exists on in the registry it skips the actual upload.

Comment: Sounds like its pushing, it says "image successfully pushed" and for images that exist it says "image already exists"

Comment: @Vlad could there be something in my dockerfile that is causing invalidation?  I didn't post the whole thing, I have some `wget` calls and other scripts running in the main docker image. Could that somehow be related? I thought that once a base image was made the instructions in that image won't be run again, so I don't see how it could cause an invalidation

Comment: You right once you build the image it's static and should never change.  Unless you have some ONBUILD commands in your base image,  they will be run every time you build the dependent image.  Can you build your test image a few times that run `docker images --tree` and post the result in your quetion

Comment: @Vlad I don't seem to have the option for a `--tree` flag. I'm using docker version 1.7

Comment: Can you include in your question the actual `docker push` command you are using, as well as the output of `docker images` showing both your base image and the newly generated image?

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with a particular version of artifactory I was using. Later versions didn't exhibit this behavior